# Swiftmailer send status

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

How to check send status in swiftmailer with symfony?

I send mails this way:
`$res = $this->get('mailer')->send($message)`
Now `$res` has always status `1` even if I set wrong password in parameters. Email isn't send and status is `1` :/

I'd like to throw some kind of information if there is any problem with sending :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use second argument in `send()`

```
 $res = $this->get('mailer')->send($message, $errors)
```

Comment: I have `1` still even password is incorrect. `dump($errors)` recieves empty array. `Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "name@domain.coml" using 2 possible authenticators` so I should get some error or `0` as code but I have `1`

Comment: `send()` method returns value of the number of reciepients who where accepted for delivery.  Second option returns not delivered emails. So with send() I cant handle connection status. So how can I check if mailer is connected to smtp server?

Answer (score 0):

```
        try {
            $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
        }
        catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $errors = $exception->getMessage();
        }
```

The `$errors` variable will contain the message if sending fails.